Self Join to remove duplicate records
I have the following :
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[a_table1]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [caseID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [officeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [location] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO a_table1 VALUES (23, 44, 'hq') 
INSERT INTO a_table1 VALUES (86, 44, 'hq') 
INSERT INTO a_table1 VALUES (26, 44, 'hq') 
INSERT INTO a_table1 VALUES (32, 44, 'hq') 

INSERT INTO a_table1 VALUES (15, 34, 'satellite') 
INSERT INTO a_table1 VALUES (32, 34, 'satellite') 
INSERT INTO a_table1 VALUES (33, 34, 'satellite') 
INSERT INTO a_table1 VALUES (86, 34, 'satellite') 
INSERT INTO a_table1 VALUES (17, 34, 'satellite') 

SELECT * 
FROM a_table1 

This is the desired output :



caseID
OfficeID




23
44


86
44


26
44


32
44


15
44


33
44


17
44



Basically, get all caseIds from hq location, and get only caseIds that do not exist in the satellite locations.
Any ideas?

you could create two CTEs (one for each office) and do a join between them using a "where not exists" or something like that.

moving each satellite into hq only if that caseId is not already there.

Your problem  statement is not clear to me.  Do you wish to actually update the table to reassign satellite case assignments to hq (when not a duplicate), deleting the duplicates?  Or do you wish to just query the distinct caseid's between the two offices with a fixed officeid = 44 in the query result?

One solution is to do:
select caseid, (select top 1 officeid 
                from a_table1 where location = 'hq') as officeid
from (select distinct caseid from a_table1) x

Result:
 caseid  officeid 
 ------- -------- 
 15      44       
 17      44       
 23      44       
 26      44       
 32      44       
 33      44       
 86      44       

See running example at db<>fiddle.

This also works.
DECLARE @hqID int

SELECT @hqID = officeId
FROM a_table1
WHERE location = 'hq'

SELECT t1.caseId, @hqID
FROM a_table1 t1
LEFT JOIN  ( SELECT *
            FROM a_table1 
            WHERE officeID = @hqID ) t2 on t2.caseID = t1.caseID
WHERE t2.CaseID IS  NULL 

UNION 

SELECT caseId, t1.officeID
FROM a_table1 t1
WHERE t1.officeID = @hqID 
ORDER BY CaseId 


Self explanatory I would say:
select * from a_table1
where location = 'hq' or caseID not in (
    select caseID from a_table1 where location = 'hq'
);

That return HQ's office ID instead:
select caseID,
    min(case when location = 'hq' then OfficeID end) over () as officeID
from a_table1
where location = 'hq' or caseID not in (
    select caseID from a_table1 where location = 'hq'
);

Assumes that caseID can't be null. Always be careful that subqueries using not in don't return a null. Presumably this doesn't apply here but I can't be certain.
That can just be simplified to:
select distinct caseID,
    min(case when location = 'hq' then OfficeID end) over () as officeID
from a_table1;

